# Response Cookie not getting set in Kohana

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

I'm trying to pull out the value of a cookie from the response of an external request in Kohana 3.2

```
$response = Request::factory('http://myurl')->execute();
echo $response->cookie('cookie');
```

Now in my example above, the server response from 'http://myurl' is setting the cookie `cookie`. In fact, if I do `print_r($response->headers());` I can see the cookie being set in the set-cookie header.

But yet when I just try to access the cookie from `$response->cookie('cookie');` I don't get anything.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What outputs when you run the following echo Debug::vars($response->cookie()); exit;

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem - I solved it using `$response->headers('Cookie')`